# how to send to another jsp page not first thing what using for

Tags: java, forms, jsp, for-loop, input

I am making about admin page. I want to accept to my member who is sign up. I using 2 jsp page one is to display and send a data(product code), another is receive the data.

The Problem is, If I click the accepct button to one person, which is place column not first, other person is accpected who is place first cloumn.

Here is the code.

admin_members.jsp

```
<form name="form_n" class="form_n" method="POST" action="save/admin_mem_accept.jsp">
    <table class="no_members table" data-toggle="table" data-show-refresh="true">
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Accept</th>
        </tr>
                <%
                    Vector userid_n = new Vector();
                    Vector user_name_n = new Vector();

                    Connection con= null;
                    Statement st =null;
                    ResultSet rs =null;

                    try {
                        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e ) {
                        out.println(e);
                    }

                    try{
                        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/becomeus?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8","root","qlzjadjtm!2");
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        out.println(e);
                    }

                    try {
                        st = con.createStatement();
                        String sql = "select * from members where isok="+false;
                        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                        if (!rs.next()) {
                            out.println("<tr><td colspan='3' align='center'>");
                            out.println("No Customers.");
                            out.println("</td></tr>");
                        } else {
                            do {
                                userid_n.addElement(rs.getString("userid"));
                                user_name_n.addElement(rs.getString("user_name"));
                            } while(rs.next());
                            int totalrows = userid_n.size();

                            for (int j=0; j<=(totalrows-1); j++) {
                                user_id = (String)userid_n.elementAt(j);

                                out.println("<tr>");
                                out.println("<td>"+userid_n.elementAt(j)+"</td>");
                                out.println("<td>"+user_name_n.elementAt(j)+"</td>");
                                out.println("<td><input type='hidden' id='input_"+j+"' name='userid' value='"+userid_n.elementAt(j)+"'></td>");
                                //out.println("<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onClick='isok_accept("+userid_n.elementAt(j)+");'>Accept</button></td>");
                                out.println("<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onClick='submit_n();'>Accept</button></td>");
                                out.println("</tr>");
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
                        out.println(e);
                    }
                %>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is code what display and send the data. I using "input" tag because to send the data.

admin_mem_accept.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*,java.util.*" %> 
<%
String userid = request.getParameter("userid");

String query = new String();
Connection conn = null;
Statement  stmt = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

try {
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e ) {
    out.println(e);
}

try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/becomeus?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8","root","qlzjadjtm!2");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    query = "update members set isok="+true+" where userid=?";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    pstmt.setString(1, userid);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
} catch(SQLException e){
    out.println(e);
} finally {
    conn.close();
}

response.sendRedirect("../admin_members.jsp");
%>
```

Here is another code to receive the data.

Is that problem about using "input"? How can I send to one person not first?
Thank you.

Comment: The problem is you didn't mention any specific id while clicking button. So I hope it is taking the first value as default. My suggestion would be pass the specifc id of the row to javascript function and send the ajax request to delete the particular record. After successful deletion refresh the page.

Comment: Hi. I solved this problem using javascript other way. Thank you for the comment!